# Autoreply on specific email-address in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, auto-reply

In Exchange 2010, is there a way using Powershell to make an autoreply for a specific email-address instead of a specific user? I have users who is about to change their primary reply-address and I want their old address to give a response that it is no longer in use. I still want the adress to forward mail to the primary address.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant do it for a e-mail address then simply create a new user and add the old e-mail adress to the new user. Then set up for that new user with the old e-mail address a forward and a autoresponse.

But i dont see a problem just keeping the old address and using the new one as primary. when time goes by every contact will use the new address.

Edit: You also have the possibilty to create transport rules. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995961%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

Comment: The only solution seems to be to this manually, as you stated. It's about 30 users that's involved in this which is doable to create new users for each. However, it would be nice to automatically do this so it doesn't matter how many users are affected.

Comment: The choice is not up to me as I'm a consultant and pretty just much have to do as I'm told :P However, if it's not possible, it's not possible. Thanks anyway.

Transport rule drops the mail and there seems to be no way to get around this.